# does oracle cloud infrastructure supports ACLs?

Tags: python, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-object-storage

I am curious regarding whether OCI object storage supports ACLs at the object and bucket levels? I have gone through their documentation and found out that they don't support ACLs at the object level. so wanted to confirm whether they support ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the read and write to objects in a bucket based on user or group:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Security/Reference/objectstorage_security.htm